# Why I cant use Random.Range code system on Unity 2D

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, random

I was using this code in unity 2D:

```
    float nilaiRandom;
    void Start()
    {
        nilaiRandom = Random.Range(1.11f, -1.88f);
        transform.position = new Vector2(transform.position.x, nilaiRandom);
    }
```

Unity count Error it says:`Assets\Go.cs(14,23): error CS0104: 'Random' is an ambiguous reference between 'UnityEngine.Random' and 'System.Random'`
What actually happened to my unity and what is the solution? please help me

Answer (score 7, accepted):

.Net comes with [`System.Random`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.random?view=netcore-3.1) and Unity comes with [`UnityEngine.Random`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Random.html). If you have both `using System` and `using UnityEngine` then there is ambiguity between them. Qualify the name to disambiguate:

```
UnityEngine.Random.Range(1.11f, -1.88f);
```

Comment: @Mr.Aby if it solved your problem consider accepting the answer so that your question doesn't remain unanswered.

Comment: my bad, im new to stack overflow